# Error when removing duplicates through a filter in a Excel macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to remove duplicate rows of data when I have a specified value in column A.

```
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim dRange As Range
    Set dRange = Range("A2:P" & lr)
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False


    Dim fRange As Range
    With dRange
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="BEAM LENGTH"
        Set fRange = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    Range(fRange).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 3, 7, 8, 9)
```

The code brings an error in `Range(fRange).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 3, 7, 8, 9)` that the `Method 'Range' of object'_Global'failed`. I'm curious as to why `fRange` is not an acceptable value for the `Range()` object, as I assume that is what brings the error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `fRange` appears to already be a Range Object... why do you need to put it back within a `Range()` call?  Try just using `fRange.Remove...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

frange in already a range. Try

```
fRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 3, 7, 8, 9)
```

Comment: I tend to not like answering questions in the comments (although it seems to be fairly common on SO for these sorts of questions)

Comment: Well I certainly don't feel like the smartest tool in the shed right now. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @JohnColeman Probably a candidate for closure regarding "simple typographical error"...

Comment: @Chrimas007 -- I have to learn how to mark questions for closure. I still haven't figured out how to use many of the SO features.